# How to decrypt files encrypted by 'Space Rangers AOL.COM Ransomware'?

Tags: windows, encryption, virus, malware

My Windows Server 2012 R2 system was infected by **'Space Rangers AOL.COM' ransomware** and all files were encrypted. All files have extension with '.wallet'.

Is there a way to decrypt/recover the files? Unfortunately I don't have any backup files.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources that may be of help to you are as follows:

- [ID Ransomware](https://id-ransomware.malwarehunterteam.com/) is a website that attempts to identify the specific ransomware threat you've been attacked with by analyzing the ransomware note displayed on your computer, or a sample encrypted file. From the website:

> Upload a ransom note and/or sample encrypted file to identify the ransomware that has encrypted your data.

It is also able to provide information on next steps to take if there are known methods for decrypting your files, though the site itself does not provide this service:

> This service is strictly for identifying what ransomware may have encrypted your files. It will attempt to point you in the right direction, and let you know if there is a known way of decrypting your files.

- [No More Ransom](https://www.nomoreransom.org/index.html) is a site launched by several security organizations, including Kaspersky and Intel Security. It provides links to tools for decrypting files attacked by several Ransomware threats (visit the site to see the current list). From the website:

> If you have been infected with one of these types of ransomware click on the link under its name and it will lead you to a decryption tool

This site also has information about [preventing a ransomware attack](https://www.nomoreransom.org/prevention-advice.html), reproduced here for convenience:

> 1. Back-up! Back-up! Back-up! Have a recovery system in place so a ransomware infection can’t destroy your personal data forever. It’s
>      best to create two back-up copies: one to be stored in the cloud
>      (remember to use a service that makes an automatic backup of your
>      files) and one to store physically (portable hard drive, thumb drive,
>      extra laptop, etc.). Disconnect these from your computer when you are
>      done. Your back up copies will also come in handy should you
>      accidentally delete a critical file or experience a hard drive
>      failure.
> 2. Use robust antivirus software to protect your system from ransomware. Do not switch off the ‘heuristic functions’ as these help
>      the solution to catch samples of ransomware that have not yet been
>      formally detected.
> 3. Keep all the software on your computer up to date. When your operating system (OS) or applications release a new version, install
>      it. And if the software offers the option of automatic updating, take
>      it.
> 4. Trust no one. Literally. Any account can be compromised and malicious links can be sent from the accounts of friends on social
>      media, colleagues or an online gaming partner. Never open attachments
>      in emails from someone you don’t know. Cybercriminals often distribute
>      fake email messages that look very much like email notifications from
>      an online store, a bank, the police, a court or a tax collection
>      agency, luring recipients into clicking on a malicious link and
>      releasing the malware into their system.
> 5. Enable the ‘Show file extensions’ option in the Windows settings on your computer. This will make it much easier to spot potentially
>      malicious files. Stay away from file extensions like ‘.exe’, ‘.vbs’
>      and ‘.scr’. Scammers can use several extensions to disguise a
>      malicious file as a video, photo, or document (like hot-chics.avi.exe
>      or doc.scr).
> 6. If you discover a rogue or unknown process on your machine, disconnect it immediately from the internet or other network
>      connections (such as home Wi-Fi) — this will prevent the infection
>      from spreading.